# Evaluating curl(curl 1/r) at r=0

Tags: vector-analysis

Although the question arose in a physics book (A. Messiah, Quantum Mechanics p. 939), it is purely a mathematical problem.
I would like to evaluate the expression ($r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$)
\begin{equation}
\vec{B}=\nabla \times (\nabla \times \frac{\vec{m}}{r}),
\end{equation}
which arises for the magnetic field of a magnetic moment $\vec{m}$ (independent of $r$), at $r=0$. Messiah first uses a standard vector analysis relation to get
\begin{equation}
\nabla(\vec{m}\cdot\nabla)\frac{1}{r} - \vec{m}\Delta\frac{1}{r},
\end{equation}
and then splits the terms as
\begin{equation}
-\tfrac{2}{3}\vec{m}\Delta\frac{1}{r} +[\nabla(\vec{m}\cdot\nabla) - \tfrac{1}{3}\vec{m}\Delta]\frac{1}{r}.
\end{equation}
Whereas the first term is well known from the Laplace equation, Messiah argues that the second term ($[...]\frac{1}{r}$) vanishes. He states that this can be seen if you integrate $[...]\frac{1}{r}$ multiplied with a test function $f(\vec{r})$ around a small domain around $r=0$, expand $f(\vec{r})$ in spherical harmonics and let $r\rightarrow 0$. However, I can really not follow how this works. Could somebody perhaps give an alternative explanation for this? Thank you very much!

P.S. the problem can be found [here](http://www.welkinsky.com/Physics_references/Physics_references/Albert_Messiah_files/Quantum%20Mechanics%20Albert%20Messiah.pdf) on p. 67 (please tell me if I am not allowed to link this).